# Recommended way to create a joint table using ruby on rails: rails generate scaffold, rails generate model, or rails generate migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I want to create a third table to indicated the many-to-many relation between table A and table B. Say table A corresponds to a Course model and table B correspond to a Subject table. Which of the following way do you recommend to generate the third joint table:

1. rails generate scaffold Course_subject course_id:integer subject_id:integer
2. rails generate model course_subject
3. rails generate migration course_subject understanding

My understanding is that using option 1 will generate the controller, model and view; option 2 doesn't generate the controller so if I want to see the result on website I will need to create the view file by hand; options 3 simply generates a migration file, nothing else. Am I getting this correctly? And is option 1 more convenient or not necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it correctly. They are all correct as long as it serves its purpose. It boils down to what you want to accomplish.

Option 1 will give you everything you need but that will give you unnecessary `views`. In rails, you still have control over your files/code. Removing a file is just a click away. Scaffolding is just a tool to help us develop apps with less effort.

If it is a basic association where you only have foreign keys, then you can use option 2. Generate a model with a migration. You can generate controller later when you need it.

Option 3 will generate a migration but will not include the `CourseSubject` model. You have to create it yourself. `Course` and `Subject` model  should define `has_many` associations and `CourseSubject` model with `belongs_to` association. This will make `course.subjects` chaining work.

```
class CourseSubject
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

Comment: Thanks @neume. Do I need to add 'belongs_to' association into the migration file for 'course_subject' as well? I did this and it won migrate correctly when deployed on heroku:                                                                         
 'class CreateCourseSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :course_subjects do |t|
      t.string :course_code
      t.string :subject_id
      t.belongs_to :course
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end'

Answer (score 1):

Command 1 creates a resource from scratch: migration, model, routing, controller and views. It also creates tests and some assets:

```
$ rails g scaffold course_subject course_id:integer subject_id:integer
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20181022020611_create_course_subjects.rb
  create    app/models/course_subject.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/course_subject_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/course_subjects.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :course_subjects
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/course_subjects_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/course_subjects
  create      app/views/course_subjects/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/course_subjects/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/course_subjects/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/course_subjects/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/course_subjects/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/controllers/course_subjects_controller_test.rb
  create      test/system/course_subjects_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/course_subjects_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  invoke    jbuilder
  create      app/views/course_subjects/index.json.jbuilder
  create      app/views/course_subjects/show.json.jbuilder
  create      app/views/course_subjects/_course_subject.json.jbuilder
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/course_subjects.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/course_subjects.scss
  invoke  scss
  create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.scss
```

Command 2 creates migration, model and test for model:

```
$ rails g model course_subject
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20181022020655_create_course_subjects.rb
  create    app/models/course_subject.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/course_subject_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/course_subjects.yml
```

Command 3 creates migration only:

```
$ rails g migration course_subject
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20181022020717_course_subject.rb
```

Which option to choose depends on association you're going to use. For plain `has_and_belongs_to_many` association you do not need a model for a join table. Just create a migration then - command 3 is your choice. Note that the join table should follow some [naming rules](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) and in this case be named `courses_subjects`. Example of migration:

```
create_table courses_subjects, id: false do |t|
  t.references  :course
  t.references  :subject
end
```

(Fields `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` are not created since they are not necessary here)

Otherwise, if for some reason you're going to have access to join table using model class, or for `has_many ... through` association, you will need to create a model as well. So use command 2 then.